# How to use session id from one page to another page?

Tags: php, mysql

In home page (http://mysite.com/) Running in one separate page.

when click the login button from(http://mysite.com/) this page, it will be redirect to another page.

I want to do the following below:

Before login, on the home page the chat function will be offline..
After login the other page the chat function will be online on home page.

How do I link these two pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to use `session_start();` at top of pages.

And make sure that when they log in, you set `$_SESSION['loggedin'] == TRUE;` and then unset the session var on log out.

```
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == TRUE){
     //include chatbox code or whatever it is
}else{
    //don't add an else if you don't want anything if not logged in, but if you do, code away here
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `session_start();` :)

Comment: @BenFortune Thanks Ben! Just updated! :)

Comment: Thank you for your responses.   But the login page works in separate..there is no link in home page.Home page works in separate.how to change that?I am included session_start();

Comment: @softwaredoubts Just make sure you include `session_start();` in both pages, and wherever the login script is, make sure that you set `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks to all.This function working ..